# UILabel cuts top of text

Tags: ios, xamarin, autolayout

I've added UILabel to my app, but upper characters of the label cuts off (see pic). I've tried to to use properties like ContentMode, but it gives me same result.

```
Font = Fonts.GetFont(FontName.HelveticaProHVCN, 30),
Lines = 2,        
TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center,
LineBreakMode = UILineBreakMode.WordWrap,
ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit,
```

http://oi59.tinypic.com/ay0bk8.jpg

Comment: i've added height of label in constraints so now everything looks fine, but anyway i'm looking for better solution

Comment: This was may be problem due to constraint or may be due to your custom font property.

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: You should host your image in StackOverflow. That external link sucks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic case of conflicting constraints. Most probably your label is not getting enough height to get laid out completely because of conflicting constraints (UILabel has an intrinsic content height but your constraints are not allowing it to stretch to that height).

1. Try running this command

   [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]

This would help you track down whether you have an ambiguous layout or not.

2. If you do have an ambiguous layout, then start looking at your constraints and see which ones are conflicting with the label height. You can check constraints along Y axis using the following command on label's superview

   [superView constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis:UILayoutConstraintAxisVertical]
3. Fix the conflicting constraint.

I wrote a blog post sometime back regarding debugging autolayout issues. Please ignore the grammatical mistakes in the article :).

[My Blog Post](http://aniosdeveloper.blogspot.in/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: UILabel is first on my view and i can use one or two lines, of text. But anyway label's top is not showing. So i think this issue is about custom font as @MaheshAgrawal wrote.